# Promise rejected in POST login using fetch API in reactjs and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a simple login using POST Fetch in Reactjs with NodeJs API. The code is working good and redirect the page when we login using correct username and password but the problem is when using fake username. I got the error in console.log with Promise : "Rejected". And I still can not figure it why

Here is the code in login.js

```
async SubmitLogin(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //debugger;
  console.log(this.state)
  await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
  })
  .then ((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    // then Read the response as json.
    else {
      let result = response.json();
      console.log(result)
      if(result === 'Invalid'){
        console.log(response)
        alert('Invalid User');
        //this.props.history.push('/login');
      }
        else {
          alert('Login Sucessfull');
          this.props.history.push('/home');
        }
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error();
  })
}
```

in my server.js, I used express-session like this:

```
//sales login
app.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => { //jsonParser,
    let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log("req: ",req.body);
    if (username && password) {
        dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`, [username, password], (err, results, fields) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;
        res.redirect('/home');
        console.log(results)
        console.log("req: ", req.body);
            } else {
                res.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
        res.send('Welcome back, ' + req.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        res.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

and this is the result I got in console:
[image]

hopefully my question is clear.

Comment: The error's pretty clear? Whatever you're getting back is not JSON, so maybe log that to console and see what it actually is. Also, don't use `alert`, not even for debugging. Use `console.log` and `console.error`, which can actually log _the real data_ instead of an often-terrible-toString value.

Comment: what should I do to fix this error,,, how to getting back JSON?

Comment: Consider using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and OAuth/OpenID for login. You can do this easily with [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/). Besides the fact that it's 2020 and I don't think any site should force you to create a login anymore, you're storing passwords in cleartext, which is a big no-no.

Comment: thanks ... I am a new here and still learning in using passport.js

Comment: your client code is saying it expects JSON code, but your server is sending plain strings, so either update your server to start sending JSON (e.g. send `{ status: "success", msg: "..." }`) or update your client to expected the response to be `text/plain`, not `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I already solved it

Comment: then please either post the solution you went with as an anaswer, or delete your question - just don't leave it hanging around unanswered (because that won't help future visitors)

Answer (score 1):

I think your response doesnt come json format.You cant parse string to json.

Your response should be like this `res.send({success:false , message : "Incorrect Username and/or Password!"})`

Answer (score 0):

After many suggestions and anwers, finally I can figure out how to solved this problem. Here is the code in login.js

```
  //submit function
  async SubmitLogin(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
    await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
    .then ((response) => {
      if(response.status === 401) {
          throw new Error('Unauthorized');
      }
      //return response.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.props.history.push('/home');
      alert('Login Sucessfull');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log();
    })
  }
```

and in the backend, I didn't change anything.